# Akka Actor Memory Leak or Management

Tags: scala, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, akka

do you have any experience with akka actor memory management/leak. Here I have a module use akka actor to communicate with other modules, but as time goes by one of module went down, because of heap memory size.

Is it necessary to send poison pill to children actor after it finished? Because every request in, I'd like to make another actor, each request. Is it necessary to send poison pill again in children actor, if they have their own children actor also?

ps: I'm using Scala Akka

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, every Actor you create needs to be stopped explicitly. This is typically done by calling `context.stop(self)` from within the Actor (if it can determine that it is finished with its task) or having the supervisor stop it using `context.stop(child)`.

Comment: how about using PoisonPill ? Will it stop its children, and children's of its children ? Or should I send PoisonPill every instantiation?

Comment: Actor termination is always recursive, no matter how it starts.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent running out of memory you can use bounded message queue aka mailbox on the receiving actor: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/mailboxes.html.

To pick how you want to manage child actors (restart, kill, etc) use supervisor strategy:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html. Supervisor strategy can be picked at any level/parent.

Comment: how about this scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685129/akka-poisonpill-wil-it-kill-descendent-of-its-children ?