# Akka PoisonPill wil it kill descendent of its children?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am using poison pill to kill children (Bx) actor of an actor (A). Each children have another children (Cx) and beyond. So it would like `A -> B1 -> C1,C2,C3 -> Dx`. Is it enough if I just send PoisonPill to actor B, then it will kill descendent actors below?

Thanksa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, once the actor receives `PoisonPill` message, it stop taking anymore messages and send stop to child actors.

Its clear from actor lifecycle that the parent actor will kill any child actors during `preRestart` and wait for its termination, before the parent actor is stopped. In you case dont want children to stop, then `override preRestart` to directly call `postStop`.

Comment: Send stop to child actors (A->B), will it send stop signal from B to its descendents also and further (B->C, C->D) ?

Comment: It will. Unless you override `preRestart` to change the default behavior, all actors, before stopping will kill its child actors. So in your case if you send `PoisonPill` to actor `A`, `B, C and D` will be killed before actor A stops, even if `C` is the child actor of `B` and `D` is the child actor of `C`.