# Akka actor memory leak using Akka Http

Tags: scala, memory-leaks, akka, actor, akka-http

I am using Akka-http with scala. I've a class MainApp which is initialized at the startup and has a ActorRef.

```
abstract class MainApp{
  def actorSystem: ActorSystem
  def myService: ActorRef
  def stop(): Unit = {
    actorSystem.terminate()
  }
}
```

```
object MyMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-actor-system")
    implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher
    val app = new MainApp {
      override def actorSystem: ActorSystem = system
      val dbPool: MyDbManagement = new MyDbManagement(someConfig)
      override def preProcessorService: ActorRef =
        actorSystem.actorOf(
          Props(new MyService(actorSystem, dbPool))
            .withDispatcher("processing-dispatcher")
        )
    }

    val httpBindingFuture = Http().newServerAt("0.0.0.0",httpPort).bind(app.http.route)
....//start server and add shutDown hooks
```

The actor class receives a message and looks like the following

```
class MyService(actorSystem, dbPool){

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case SendMessage(request) => {
      val actorSender = sender()
      implicit val executionContext = actorSystem.dispatchers.lookup("db-blocking-dispatcher")

      try {
        val encryptedReq = dbPool.encrypt(request)
        val responseFuture = dbPool.sendToDb(request)

        responseFuture.onComplete { //handle error codes and return something like
           actorSender ! MyResponse(202, "Accepted")
        }
    }
}
```

I've one http route, which asks the message

```
path("send") {
  post {
    entity(as[MyPojo]) { request =>
      onSuccess(app.MyService ? SendMessage(request)) {
        case response: MyResponse => {
          complete(response.statusCode, response)
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

**Problem-Statement:** I've created only 1 actor in the application but there are multiple dispatchers(fork-join-executor) which performs multiple tasks and to free the default-dispatcher so that it can accept non-blocking incoming requests. Number of incoming requests are very high.
This application has a memory leak and degrades over time(heap size increases and full GC occurs which takes time and CPU)
I've taken a heap dump when it was in the degraded state.
During the investigation on MAT tool,
the major leak suspect was *LocalActorRef*

> One instance of "akka.actor.LocalActorRef" loaded by "jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader @ 0x609c0ee58" occupies ~7GB (95.80%) bytes.

```
Class Name              |   Shallow Heap  | Retained Heap

akka.actor.LocalActorRef|       24        |  ~ 7 GB
```

I would like to know what is causing this memory leak?

***If there are any more design related questions or suggestions, let me know.***

I've gone through the following but none helped:
https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/localactorref-memory-leak-and-full-gc-allocation-failure-causing-gc-to-take-too-long/7216/6

[Akka Actor Memory Leak or Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668716/akka-actor-memory-leak-or-management)

> I've also thought of using Futures but with Futures the application has higher latencies

Comment: First of all, by using `?`, you are in fact using `Future`.

Comment: I also note that your heap dump is showing that the graph reachable from that `LocalActorRef` comprises 7GB.  That does not in any way imply that the `LocalActorRef` is responsible for the leak.  If I had to guess, just from the code you're posting, the leak is in the `dbpool`.

Comment: a `LocalActorRef` holds a reference to the `ActorSystem`, which will hold a reference to every actor on the system, which between them will hold a reference to nearly everything.

Comment: I think you shouldn't pass `actorSystem` via constructor. Use `context.system` inside the actor to access the actor system.

Comment: Also, maybe assigning sender to a val and using it in a callback is causing issues. [The docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.32/futures.html#use-the-pipe-pattern) recommend using `pipeTo` to send a result of a future to the sender, so your code could look like: `responseFuture.map(_ => MyResponse(202, "Accepted")).pipeTo(sender())`